# Is it good way to write all js code in html page and include that html page in another html page instead of .js file?

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates

I just want to know that is it a good idea to write all javascript code in an HTML(instead of writing in .js) file and that the HTML file will be included in another HTML file.
I'm writing javascript code in an HTML file because I can access Django templates in an HTML file. Django templates are not accessible in pure JS files.

Comment: I would advice you **not to render** into javascript using Django. If you want some urls in your javascript render them as some attributes on some html tag. If you want some data then render them in the html using the [`json_script` template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#json-script)

Answer (score 0):

It'll really depend on your project. If the script is as simple as to show an alert box or something then by all means keep it in the same html file.

But if you need much more complex things then it's always better to have a separate file for each of the requirements. Because when the project gets bigger you'll have a hard time going through some thousand line of code. But if those are in separate files readability becomes much easier